# What are the challenges of installing Shopify on a root domain and Wordpress as a subfolder?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo, subdomain, shopify

We have a Shopify store and a Wordpress CMS site.  Currently the shop is on the root domain and Wordpress is on a subdomain (help.domain.com).  Everything is fine, life is good.

Our SEO company, predictably, is now asking us to merge the Wordpress side at help.domain.com into the root by installing Wordpress in a subfolder.

Is it even possible?

My understanding is that such an architecture introduces a slew of technical issues and potential headaches.

I suppose my question is how big of a challenge is this and what types of issues should I expect to face.  Moreover, does the benefit outweigh the cost.

Comment: It's easy, if there is no actual integration between WP and Shopify, WordPress in a subdirectory isn't an issue at all.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: I was specifically asking about the feasibility of such a configuration and potential technical pitfalls.

Comment: WordPress administration, management best practices, and server configuration are also off topic, as explained in the tag wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make WP a subdirectory of Shopify. You must continue to keep it as a subdomain. So while your Shopify can be **domain.com**, your WP must continue to be something like **help.domain.com**.

Your SEO company is flailing at windmills. Not unusual. If they were good, you might instead be receiving advice on how to leverage the content of your domain as a total package, rather than how you choose to organize it. The organization in terms of domain setup is so not important compared to the content within.